# How do I transfer a Classification Machine Learning Model from one data set to another?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I've recently built a multi class classification machine learning model through sklearn and I want to transfer the learnings from one dataset to another.

I have our first party data (let's call it Sales) which includes the names of thousands of text books and the disciplines they belong to (i.e. Biology 101 (title) is a Biology (discipline) textbook). I was able to get the machine to fairly accurately predict the discipline of a textbook based on the title of the book.

I now have a second data set which contains Competitor text book titles, but no disciplines. I want to have the machine guess the disciplines for the competitor text books based on what it learned from the Sales data set.

The Sales Machine Learning model works well on the Sales side. So here is what I want to do:

1) Transfer the learnings from the Sales model to the Competitor set.

2) Export the results of that transfer to a CSV.

3) In order to do the machine learning model from Sales and Competitor I stripped all other columns of data, ideally I'd like to export the predicted discipline for both data sets.

If anyone could even point me in the right direction of documentation on transferring my model I would appreciate it.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you want to achieve. But, do read about 'Transfer Learning'. I believe that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already familiar with `scikit-learn` then this should be an easy task.

Here is some high-level pseudo-code:

```
sales_data = preprocess_data(raw_data_sales) # normalization, vectorization, etc.
model.fit(sales_data,sales_labels) # potentially with cross-validation, hyperparameter-tuning etc.

competitor_data = preprocess_data(competitor_raw_data) # same preprocessing as for train data
sales_predictions = model.predict(sales_data)
competitor_predictions = model.predict(competitor_data)
export_to_CSV(sales_predictions) # export predictions to CSV
export_to_CSV(competitor_predictions)
```

There is actually no need for 'transfer learning' here since you don't have any labels for your competitor data. What you like to achieve sounds like simple inference.

`export_to_CSV()` could be a `numpy` (`np.savetxt()`) or a `pandas` (`df.to_csv()`) function, whatever you like to use. To map your non-numeric labels (the disciplines) back and forth from text to numbers you can use scikit-learn's `LabelEncoder`.

**Note**: Since your data comes from two different sources and you cannot train the model on the data from the second source but only on your own sales data (since you have no labels from your competitor), the performance of your model might be worse than on your sales data. If you would have additional labels from your competitor, then this would be a transfer learning task since you could use your initial model and continue training.

Comment: Hi Tinu - Thanks for your response. I'm not as familiar with Scikit-learn as I should be. I was following this guide: https://datascienceplus.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-scikit-learn/ 

I still wasn't able to get it to work with pseudo-code since I'm not sure how to work with just a single column of data on the competitor side.

I'm going to spend the next few days trying to pick up Scikit Learn through Udemy to maybe figure out specifically what I need to do to finish this thing up.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could provide the error messages of your code.

Comment: Hi again - there is no error message, I just don't know how to proceed with the script I have which ends at the same place the datascienceplus article ends. I've uploaded my competitor set, I just don't know how to apply the machine learning model I have to that single column of competitor product titles and then export the results.